# Crystal Reports 9 Graphs/Chart

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I have a cross tab with data showing clients per hour per day.  So the rows are days of the week and the columns are the hours of the day, with the values being the number of clients.

Now to the main point :), I want to produce a graph for each day of the week, that shows the number of clients per hour for that day.  So the report would have 8 graphs in total, one for each day and then an "all days" graph. See Picture:

[Click, as I can't include pictures yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9tST.jpg)

Any idea how to do this, as I can't find a filter or anything, and the only graph I can get is all on one, with multiple bar lines for the days, in each hour block.

Comment: Any ideas?  This is driving me crackers :)
I have managed to get it to show Monday's and the Total for the whole week.  I can then set the colour of the total bar to be transparent, but the values are then way off.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, just figured this out :)

I have created a formula for each week day, that contains the following:

if {Command.day} = "Monday" 
then {Command.kpi1}
else 0

Then in the chart expert, use this formula field for the values...so simple but overlooked :@